# Why won't the color #e67d22e1 display in Safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

For some reason, the color `#e67d22e1` will not display in my specific `text`, `borders`, `btn` & also font in certain `sections` of my website.

I have tested this issue in Chrome & Firefox, but for some reason even with `prefix's`, it will not display the color in Safari.

I would really appreciate any help possible, & also constructive criticism towards the site. This is my first project.

:-)

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: #e67d22e1;
-webkit-background-color: #e67d22e1;
-webkit-border: #e67d22e1;
-webkit-border-bottom: #e67d22e1;

/* UNIVERSAL */

*,
*::before,
*::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
}

html,
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.5;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 1.375rem;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 1rem;
}

h6 {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}

p {
    font-size: 1.125rem;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* PAGE-CONTAINER */

.page-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

/* HEADER-SECTION */
#main-nav ul {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: end;
        -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
    margin-right: 2rem;
}

#main-nav li {
    margin: 1rem;
}

#main-nav a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#main-nav a:hover {
    margin-right: 0.4rem;
    color: #e67d22e1;
}

header {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6))), 
    url("/img/chopping-board/chopping-board-bg.jpg");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chopping-board/chopping-board-bg.jpg");
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chopping-board/chopping-board-bg.jpg");
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chopping-board/chopping-board-bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
}

.hero-text {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    justify-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
        align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 8rem;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.hero-text h3 {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.hero-text p {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

.hero-text .btn {
    -webkit-background-color: #e67d22e1;
    background-color: #e67d22e1;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.hero-text .btn:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    -webkit-border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
    border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
}

/* SERVICES-SECTION */

.services {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.services-heading   {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
        align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.underline {
    -webkit-border: 2px solid #e67d22e1;
    border: 2px solid #e67d22e1;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.services h1,
.services h3,
.services .underline {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #e67d22e1;
    color: #e67d22e1;
}

/* CARDS */

.cards {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.card {
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
    border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.card:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card h3,
.card p {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #e67d22e1;
    color: #e67d22e1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

#card-icon {
    -webkit-background-color: #e67d22e1;
    background-color: #e67d22e1;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    width: 4rem;
    height: 4rem;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* MENU-GALLERY-SECTION */

.menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
}

.gallery-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.gallery-container img {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    -webkit-border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
    border: 1px solid #e67d22e1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
            box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}

.gallery-container img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
}

/* ABOUT-SECTION */

.about {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6))), 
    url("/img/chef/chef-3.jpg");
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chef/chef-3.jpg");
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chef/chef-3.jpg");
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), 
    url("/img/chef/chef-3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    -webkit-border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #e67d22e1;
}

.about img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 8px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.226);
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.about h1,
.about h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1.5rem;
}

.orange {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #e67d22e1;
    color: #e67d22e1;
}

.red {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #ff0000;
    color: #ff0000;
}

/* FOOTER-SECTION */

footer {
    width: 100;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #000;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    justify-items: center;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: center;
        align-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}

#top-icon,
.email,
.phone,
#instagram,
.copyright {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

#top-icon {
    font-size: 4rem;
}

.email,
.phone {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

#instagram {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

#instagram:hover {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #e67d22e1;
    color: #e67d22e1;
}

footer .copyright {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which version you are using.
in the old versions of Safari doesn't support rgba or hex with transparency.

instead of 8-digits hex colors, you can use the ordinary colors and select the desired element and add transparency to it.